# Unimodular matrices fixing $(1, 1, \cdots, 1)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

What is known about the subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb Z)$ fixing (under left multiplication) the vector ${(1, 1, \cdots, 1)}^T$ ('T' denotes transposition). I'm particularly interested in the case $n = 5$.

Comment: It is conugate to the subgroup fixing $(1,0,\dots,0)^T$ (because these two vectors belong to the same orbit), and therefore isomorphic to $\mathrm{GL}(n-1,\mathbf{Z}) \rtimes \mathbf{Z}^{n-1}$.

Comment: The question is somewhat overly general. It is GL$(n,Z)$-conjugate (and if $ n \geq 3$,  SL$(n,Z)$-conjugate) to the direct sum of $1$ and a matrix in $GL(n-1,Z)$ (complete the singleton set consisting of the vector to a $Z$.-basis), and every such is conjugate to one of these. What did you want to know?

Comment: I misread the question: I thought it was a single matrix, which is what the first "It" refers to. But the argument still works for all elements of the subgroup (since we can take the same basis).

Comment: Thanks! The comments are informative enough.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle: maybe isomorphic to ${\bf Z}^{n-1}\rtimes {\rm GL}(n-1, {\bf Z})$? I would say that the subgroup  ${\bf Z}^{n-1}$ is a normal, while $ {\rm GL}(n-1, {\bf Z})$ is not.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Sure, thanks for pointing out the typo. I meant the group of matrices with first column equal to $(1,0,\dots,0)^T$, which is $\mathrm{GL}(n-1,\mathbf{Z}) \ltimes \mathbf{Z}^{n-1}$ for the natural action of $\mathrm{GL}(n-1,\mathbf{Z})$ on $\mathbf{Z}^{n-1}$.